# How can I add onLoad events to elements with unknown names at document load using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm using a third-party commenting plugin, and I would like to change the content of some of the buttons.  This is straightforward for buttons with `id`'s known ahead of time, but it also has buttons that don't appear until a 'Reply' button is clicked.  To be clear, these elements *are not present when the page is loaded*.  They are inserted into the DOM following some event.  For those elements, I only know a prefix of the `id`.

My first thought was to use `.on`, and to delegate to the children of the reply container, but the `load` event does not bubble, so this doesn't work:

```
<script>
  $("#container").on("load", 'a[id|="reply-button"]', function(event) { $(this).html("different text");  } );
</script>

<div id="container">
  <a id="reply-button-42das56ds6d78a">some text</a>
</div>
```

What's the next best thing?

Comment: I don't think anchors have load events

Comment: @Musa It looks like you're right.  What's the best way to change the text of an anchor after it loads, then?

Comment: Are you saying you need to be able to tell when elements have been added via some other event that you don't control? That is, you know what the id prefix of said elements will be, but you don't know exactly when they'll be added?

Comment: @nnnnnn I know they will appear when the 'Reply' button is clicked.  When that happens, new elements are inserted into the DOM, and I know what the prefix of the `id` of those elements will be.

Comment: But you don't control the 'Reply' button click code because that's in a plugin, is that right?

Comment: @AshirvadSingh: do not recommending `live()`. Use `on()` in jQuery 1.7 or `delegate()` in older version for dynamic bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I know they will appear when the 'Reply' button is clicked. When that happens, new elements are inserted into the DOM, and I know what the prefix of the id of those elements will be."*

You could use something like the `DOMSubtreeModified` event to tell when elements are added, but that isn't supported by all browsers. (In fact it has been deprecated.)

Or you could attach a click handler to the 'Reply' button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // initialise plugin here, then:
    $("some selector for the reply button(s)").click(function(e) {
        // setTimeout(function() {        
        $('a[id|="reply-button"]').html("different text");
        // }, 10);
    });
});
```

jQuery ensures that multiple event handlers will run in the order they are bound, but of course this only applies to handlers added with jQuery. So if the third-party commenting plugin you are using also uses jQuery then just be sure it is initialised first and your own reply click handler should run afterwards and at that time it will be able to access the elements added by the plugin.

If the plugin doesn't use jQuery you can't be sure your click handler will run last so instead uncomment the `setTimeout` code I've shown above - it will wait a few milliseconds to give the plugin events time to run and *then* update the text.

Comment: It's possible that the Reply button is using AJAX.  If that's the case OP will definitely need to use a setTimeout with a generous allowance for the response to come back. That said, I would be inclined to use this technique over the one I suggested.  Greater performance and perfect browser compatibility.

Comment: @ZachShipley - Yes, I didn't think about Ajax. A timeout with a greater delay would definitely be needed then. Or, perhaps forget the idea of using a click handler and just use a recurring timeout to continually poll for the existence of new links - yucky, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector `$('#^=id')`

id being the prefix

e.g all ids starting test123

`$('#^=test123')`

this would work for things like

```
test1234
test12345
test123fgjfdgj
```

This might help: http://oscarotero.com/jquery/

And use jquery event listeners for the page load..

e.g. `$(document).ready(function(){});`

If they are loaded when a button is clicked then do..

```
$('#buttonid').click(function() {//handle click});
```

Comment: How does this help with elements that do not appear in the page at load time?  Also, I'm already using the prefix selector.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for DOM Mutation Events.  This spec allows you to be notified when DOM nodes are inserted, changed, etc.  Browser support is not really there, though... well, IE is behind (IE >= 9 has support).  It's also a major performance hog.  See [this MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mutation_events).  For these reasons, I don't think a lot of folks here would suggest using them.  Here's some code, though:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('selector matching new elements')) {
        //do what you want with e.target, which is the newly-inserted element
    }
}, false);
```

There is a performance-boosting hack involving listening for CSS animation events instead: [here](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/04/25/i-want-a-damnodeinserted/).  Only problem is that IE9 does not support CSS animations.  I think we're all waiting for the day when we can use these events in a cross-browser and performant way, though.

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't hurt to mention the [DOM MutationObserver](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/) spec, too. That's the holy grail, but the browser support's even worse than the two techniques I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: If only it were not deprecated, this would have been the answer.  :)

Comment: I completely agree; I wouldn't use this on a production site either! Your question was "how do I add 'onload' events", so I thought I'd throw this in there in case anyone wanted to know how that might be done. Cheers.